# How to measure elapsed time for an MPC MCU target in C

Tags: c, time, microcontroller, elapsedtime, nxp-microcontroller

I'm developping an application that runs on an MPC5748G and i want to measure elapsed time between inside a block of code or a function.

I have used the following code but it seems it works only in windows but instead i want to do it for the microcontroller i'm using MPC.

```
    /* Program to demonstrate time taken by function fun() */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// A function that terminates when enter key is pressed
void fun()
{
    printf("fun() starts \n");
    printf("Press enter to stop fun \n");
    while(1)
    {
        if (getchar())
            break;
    }
    printf("fun() ends \n");
}

// The main program calls fun() and measures time taken by fun()
int main()
{
    // Calculate the time taken by fun()
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    fun();
    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

    printf("fun() took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course i didn't use printf on the MCU side but instead i'm using a debugger (trace 32) to read the value ...

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Configure one of the hardware timers to count ticks at an appropriate rate.  Start the timer.  Call the function you want to time.  Upon completion, check the timer's counter value register value.  Then finally, convert the number of ticks to the desired units of time.

Comment: @kkrambo thanks but it's the first time i'm doing this can you explain more ... so i have to found a timer in the MPC datasheet and access it to view it's value before and after breakpoint for example ... the final value must then be divided by the clock frequency of the MPC ?

Comment: The MPC datasheet should have a section that describes the operation of the hardware timers.  Each timer will have a handful of associated registers that are mapped into the memory address space.  Use the memory mapped registers to enable the timer, select an input clock, select a divisor of the input clock (to determine the timer tick rate), select the counting mode, start the timer, and read the counter value at a later time.  Divide the final counter value by the timer tick rate.  NXP (the manufacturer) likely provides some example software that will clear up what you read in the datasheet.

Comment: yes there are 4 different timers , each one with different conditions and different clock frequency ... where can i found how to Use the memory mapped registers to enable the timer ?  i will try to look for examples on their site